# What is the most efficient way to Navigate to a XAML page? wp8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, navigation

Suppose, I have two XAML page: MainPage.xaml & Page1.xaml.

For navigating to Page1.xaml, I always use this code:

```
Page1 mynewPage = new Page1();
this.Content = mynewPage;
```

But I see people using other codes for navigating purpose. Am I doing this in an inefficient way? What's the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***use***  this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

Answer (score 0):

In that case you have not control about, for instance going back,in your case have to create code to manage the navigation by yourself, and you might to need to store the information of each page at a time, that is automatic when you do it.

Apart there are transitions between pages that are great to show the user that the page is changing. Of course you can create your own transitions but at the end you are creating the navigation by yourself.

With navigation you can control the events of Navigating and navigated and use them to initialize the page, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In windows phone 8, you should use "NavigationService". NavigationService contains methods, properties, and events to support navigation and implemented by Microsoft.

Your code just updates content. It doesnt keep navigation history. So, you cant use back button unless override. You cant pass parameter to another view or you cant know navigation sucessfully ended.

To sum up, navigation service offers all of these features and mores. For detail  information , you can checkout in app navigation model from here: [In-app navigation for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402536(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: Please post your answer directly here, instead of just linking to another site.